# What year make and model of my haro frame

Tags: bmx

I have a haro frame that I believe is a 1986 haro group 1 but the only difference is that it doesn't have a place for the kickstand like the rest I've seen [image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Welcome to bicycles! Is this the same as http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/44056/what-year-make-and-model-is-my-haro-frame ? I think you have two copies of the same photo (the 3rd and 4th seem identical to me) which you might want to address, and it's good to see that you've taken the [tour]!